# Consuming XML restful service, outputting in JSON - for loop issue

Tags: python, xml, json, rest

I have a RESTful service on another server on the internet. I am sending that a request, which returns a single XML item with a few attributes.

I also have another python function that consumes a locally stored XML, and when I provide a parameter to it, it'll iterate through all the elements, and return only the XML item that matches that parameter, ie mysite/search/123.
I can output that fine by using:

```
from xml.dom.minidom import parseString
import json
import urllib2
from django.http import HttpResponse
    def index(request, number="1"):
        #file = urllib2.urlopen('myfile.xml')
        file = open('myfile.xml','r')
        data = file.read()
        dom = parseString(data)
        rows = dom.getElementsByTagName("root")[0].getElementsByTagName("subroot")[0].getElementsByTagName("theData")
        for row in rows:
            return  HttpResponse(json.dumps({'name':row.getAttribute("name"),'address': row.getAttribute("address"), 'phone': row.getAttribute("phone")}, sort_keys=True, indent=4))
```

Notice how I use `row` in the for loop and then access the attributes using `row.getAttribute()`. If I only have 1 XML item, there is no loop need, so no itereating, so no `row` object to use the `getAttribute()` method on.

I just want to retrieve this one piece of data. Can anyoe help?

PS, if I try do the loop on this single XML data, I get an error saying:
`TypeError: Iteration over a non-sequence`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass a generator to Django as a response:

```
response_generator = (
    json.dumps(
        {
            'name': row.getAttribute("name"),
            'address': row.getAttribute("address"),
            'phone': row.getAttribute("phone")},
        sort_keys=True,
        indent=4)
    for row in rows)

return HttpResponse(response_generator)
```

See also: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#passing-iterators

Hope it helps.

Comment: Wow, thank you very much!! Works perfect now! Actually, I have another question which I don't think warrants another thread opened, but maybe someone can help. In my urls.py I have `(r'^names/(\d{1,2})$','foo.views.index'),` which takes a number (eg mysite/names/12) and displays the XML for that, but how do I phrase the regex so I can take a string instead of an integer? eg mysite/names/john ? thanks

Comment: Please see the regexp manual at the documentation of the re package. The solution for the above: `(r'^names/(\w+)$','foo.views.index')`; Also don't forget to remove the conversion to int.